# Upgrading Spring Security to 3.2.0.RELEASE no longer provides CSRF token in Spring taglib

Tags: spring-security, csrf, taglib

My project was using Spring Security 3.2.0.RC2 and my JSP's used the Spring taglib's form:form tag to automatically insert the CSRF token into my forms.

After upgrading to Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE, I'm finding that the form:form tag no longer automatically inserts the CSRF token into my form, and that I now must manually add it via placing this in my form:
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Has anyone else encountered the same issue?  If so, what did you do for a workaround?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure you are using the `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` annotation instead of the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation as described in [Hello Spring MVC Security Java Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html#logging-out). The reason adding the new annotation was to resolve [SEC-2436](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2436). You will notice that [SEC-2463](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2463) was added to better document this within the CSRF part of the reference.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer Rob.  That did the trick.  I didn't realize that the annotation to use had changed to @EnableWebMvcSecurity in the change from Spring Security 3.2.0.RC2 to 3.2.0.RELEASE; I must have missed that in the release notes.

Thanks again.

Comment: Not an problem. As the JIRA to update the documentation alludes to this detail is not as obvious as it should be.