# What is the difference between @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableWebMvcSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

### @EnableWebSecurity

The JavaDoc documentaion:

> Add this annotation to an `@Configuration` class to have the `Spring Security` configuration defined in any `WebSecurityConfigurer` or more likely by extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` base class and overriding individual methods.

### @EnableWebMvcSecurity

The JavaDoc documentaion:

> Add this annotation to an `@Configuration` class to have the `Spring Security` configuration integrate with `Spring MVC`.

- What exactly does it mean to '*integrate with Spring MVC*' ? What extra behaviors do I get?
- I found [guides](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html#logging-out) & [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195615/upgrading-spring-security-to-3-2-0-release-no-longer-provides-csrf-token-in-spri), which suggest that this annotation adds `CSRF Tokens` to `Spring MVC` Forms, is this the only thing it adds?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you take a look at those classes, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` actually adds the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation in `WebMvcSecurityConfiguration`. Therefore, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` does everything that `@EnableWebSecurity` does, and a bit more.

What more you ask?

If you look at `WebMvcSecurityConfiguration`, you will see that it adds an `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` so that you can access the authentication principal by adding an annotation to a controller method argument. i.e.:

```
public String show(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser) {
    // do something with CustomUser
    return "view";
}
```

It also integrates with Spring Web MVC to add a CSRF token to forms.

Comment: BTW, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` will be deprecated in 4.0: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2790

Comment: Thanks @SlavaSemushin - worth knowing

Comment: when I am trying to @EnableWebSecurity it is not working with my interceptor ? is there any conflicts or do I need do some configuration for prevent the path being intercepted by the interceptor. I am using `HandleInterceptor`

Comment: I couldn't answer from that detail. It sounds like you would be better creating a new question and providing more detail of your issues.

Comment: So if `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` adds a few things that `@EnableWebSecurity` doesn't and is being deprecated, what annotation should I use now to get those extra things like CSRF?

Comment: I'm not sure what other features you're looking for (if any), but as of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF is enabled by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure

Answer (score 54):

> As of Spring Security 4.0, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` is deprecated. The replacement is
>   `@EnableWebSecurity` which will determine adding the Spring MVC features
>   based upon the classpath.
>
> *To enable Spring Security integration with Spring MVC add the*
>   `@EnableWebSecurity` *annotation to your configuration.*

[source](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/mvc.html)